# JUnit - How to run a method before Spring starts loading?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit4

I have some information in a XML config file (for example a path to log4j2 logs save folder) and want to load them before Spring starts loading. But neither `static` or `@BeforeClass` is executed before Spring and Exception is thrown (log4j2 cannot find System property, which I want to define during XML config file load).

How to run some method before Spring starts loading?

I'm using Spring Boot (Start.class as an entry point).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Start.class)
// @ContextConfiguration(classes = { Start.class }, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class FileUploadTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeClazz clazz;

    static {
        System.out.println("Static");
        assertNotNull("Conf file is not specified", System.getProperty("conf"));
        ConfigLoader.initConfiguration(System.getProperty("conf"));
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("setUp");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        System.out.println("oneTimeSetUp");
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws IOException {
```

Run output:

> 2014-12-20 14:15:46,614 ERROR Unable to create file
>   ${sys:logsPath}/sql.log java.io.IOException: Název souboru či adresáře
>   nebo jmenovka svazku je nesprávná     at
>   java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)  at
>   java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:184)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:274)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:86)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>
> 2014-12-20 14:15:46,617 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class
>   class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for
>   element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:766)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:706)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:698)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:358)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
>     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)    at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
>     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:274)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:86)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create a manager
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:184)
>     ... 43 more
>
> 2014-12-20 14:15:46,619 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in
>   Appenders. [20.12.2014 14:15:46.749] PID ${sys:PID}  INFO [main] --
>   WebTestContextBootstrapper: Using TestExecutionListeners:
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTestPropertiesListener@41ee392b,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1e67a849,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@57d5872c,
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@667a738,
>   org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@36f0f1be]
>   Static

Comment: Static block will be executed just once when you start you test. Before class will also be run just once before starting with you actual setup method. So i don't understand really what the issue is.

Comment: I've added a console output. Static is printed after log4j2 errors so I think Spring is loading before static is executed.

Comment: sys:logsPath is a System property which I want to define during XML config file load (before Spring starts loading log4j2).

Comment: Is passing this property as a jvm argument not an option?

Comment: I'm not passing it yet. I want to prepare it from XML file and after that load Sprint.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why static block is not called. But as a solution I suggest to add log4j2.xml into src/test/resources and remove all system properties - logging into file is not required for JUnit tests.

SpringJUnit4ClassRunner then loads a src/test/resources/log4j2.xml and then executes all JUnit methods (@BeforeClass, @Test..).