# How can I run code in JUnit before Spring starts?

Tags: spring-test

How can I run code in my `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` `@SpringBootTest(classes = {...})` JUnit test before Spring starts?

> This question has been asked several times (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580496/junit-how-to-run-a-method-before-spring-starts-loading), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35217354/how-to-add-custom-applicationcontextinitializer-to-a-spring-boot-application)) but was always "solved" by some configuration recommendation or other, never with a universal answer. Kindly don't question what I am about to do in that code but simply suggest a clean way to do it.

Tried so far and failed:

Extend [`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) to get a class whose constructor can run custom code before initializing Spring. Failed because `super(testClass)` must be called first thing and already does a whole lot of things that get in the way.

Extend [`Runner`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) to get a class that delegates to `SpringRunner` instead of inheriting it. This class could run custom code in its constructor before actually instantiating the SpringRunner. However, this setup fails with obscure error messages like *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig*. "Obscure" because my test has no web config and thus shouldn't meddle with sessions and cookies.

Adding an [`ApplicationContextInitializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer.html) that is triggered before Spring loads its context. These things are easy to add to the actual @SpringApplication, but hard to add in Junit. They are also quite late in the process, and a lot of Spring has already started.

Comment: I tested the "Extend Runner" option and it works for me. You should probably provide more details about your scenario: spring version, minimized and anonimized testcase. For the "Extend SpringJUnit4ClassRunner" option your constructor might look like this: `public MyCustomSpringRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError { super(doSomethingAndPassthrough(clazz)); }`;` where you do your stuff in the static method `doSomethingAndPassthrough` which then returns the class passed in as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing jannis' comment on the question, the option to create an alternative JUnit runner and let it delegate to the SpringRunner *does* work:

```
public class AlternativeSpringRunner extends Runner {

    private SpringRunner springRunner;

    public AlternativeSpringRunner(Class testClass) {
        doSomethingBeforeSpringStarts();
        springRunner = new SpringRunner(testClass);
    }

    private doSomethingBeforeSpringStarts() {
        // whatever
    }

    public Description getDescription() {
        return springRunner.getDescription();
    }

    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        springRunner.run(notifier);
    }

}
```

Being based on `spring-test` `4.3.9.RELEASE`, I had to override `spring-core` and `spring-tx`, plus `javax.servlet`'s `servlet-api` with higher versions to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to leave out `SpringRunner` and use [the equivalent combination](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules) of [`SpringClassRule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html) and [`SpringMethodRule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringMethodRule.html) instead. Then you can wrap the [`SpringClassRule`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/rules/SpringClassRule.html) and do your stuff before it kicks in:

```
public class SomeSpringTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static final TestRule TestRule = new TestRule() {
            private final SpringClassRule springClassRule =
                new SpringClassRule();

            @Override
            public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {
                System.out.println("Before everything Spring does");
                return springClassRule.apply(statement, description);
            }
        };

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Tested with 5.1.4.RELEASE Spring verison)

I don't think you can get more "before" than that. As for other options you could also check out [`@BootstrapWith`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-bootstrapwith) and [`@TestExecutionListeners`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-testexecutionlisteners) annotations.